# FPS drop when model appears - three.js

Tags: three.js, 3d-modelling

When I use `three.js` to load my Collada file, FPS is only 5-7.
I try to optimize it with Blender and Meshlab, I can load it smooth but model becomes worse.
Can anyone explain to me why my model is rendered with a low frame rate?
You can download my model right [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jGipM2GL_ol-4HRFrQefcq0TC7hE5c5i/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can anyone explain to me why my model is lag when load.

Your model is rendered with `66011` draw calls. You can see this information by inspecting the [WebGLRenderer.info](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.info) object in your debugger. Such a high amount of draw calls is unfavorable and most likely the main reason for your bad performance.

So the first thing you should try is to merge geometries in your content creation tool (e.g. Blender). Also avoid the usage of multiple materials per 3D object.

BTW: Instead of using Collada, export your model as `glTF` and then load it via `GLTFLoader`. It's the recommended 3D format of `three.js`. More information right here:

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models